# VSCode not finding type definitions for module

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, three.js

I have a .js file with //@ts-check (so it's javascript rather than typescript, but is being typed-checked and getting Intellisense info from .ts declarations.)

My .js file is at the same level as the node_modules directory.
So I import three.js like so:

```
import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/src/three.js'
```

and later I do some stuff with it. Eg:

```
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -f2, f2, f2, -f2, near, far );
camera.zoom = 0.5;
camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
camera.lookAt(origin.x, origin.y, origin.z);
```

However, according to TSC, camera.up gives error; "property up does not exist on type OrthoGraphic camera." And ditto for camera.lookAt(). It does exist however, and the code runs fine. In other words: typescript is not finding the type definitions.

However, I've installed the @types definition for three.js into the same node_modules directory so my directory structure looks like:

```
ex.js
node_modules
  + @types
    + three
  + three
```

Now, if I import like this instead:

```
import * as THREE from 'THREE';
```

and all the previously flagged errors go away. However, that doesn't run. (The browser gets a not found error when it tries to load it.)

Three.js moved over a few months ago from maintaining it's .ts declaration files as part of the three.js library, to "outsourcing it" as a separate product to the @types area. ([https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/three][1])

When that was the case, the

```
import * as THREE from './node_modules/three/src/three.js'
```

worked fine.

I have fiddled around endlessly with a tsconfig.json file - which currently looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "../dst/",
        "target": "ESNEXT",
        //"typeRoots": [
        //    "./node_modules/@types"
        //]
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*",
        "index.d.ts",   // declaration file path
    ],
    "lib": [
            "es2016"
    ]
    //"exclude": [
    //    "./node_modules",
    //]
}
```

but nothing seems to work. Can anyone shed some light on this?

NB:

1. I don't really want to convert this to a .ts file. I've only just learnt javascript and don't relish having to figure out full-blown typescript environment.
2. Yes, I could keep swapping the two import lines so that when editing I get typescript working, and then when running I get the javascript engine finding the module... but that's annoying having to do that every time I swap from editing to testing.

Comment: Instead of importing from `.../three/src/three.js`, try importing from `.../three/build/three.module.js` and see if that helps. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.module.js

Comment: @Marquizzo, yes, sorry, probably should have said, but I tried that already and it didn't work either.